# Raspbian: how ifplugd works on lo and other interface

Tags: networking, raspbian, hot-plug

On my raspbian, I'm  wondering why `ifplugd` (link detection daemon for ethernet devices) is also running on the `lo` the loopback interface.
The `ps` command displays:
 `/usr/sbin/ifplugd -i lo -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I`

There is no reason why `ifplugd` runs on `lo`, is it possible to configure it to start on all interfaces but `lo` ?